# Firemonkey app out of focus

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

So, i'm making firemonkey application, and for my vcl app's i was able to use `SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOACTIVATE);` so my app would always be on top if something else (browser) is focused at the moment. I'm trying to find something similar to do with firemonkey, are there any ideas,please? 
P.S. That code for firemonkey will be placed on OnChange event for some hidden Tedit. If it helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code still works fine except that in FMX a the `Handle` of a `TForm` is now of type `TWindowHandle` whereas it used to be of type `HWND` in VCL. You only need to convert your `TWindowHandle` to a `HWND` so you can pass it to `SetWindowPos(..)` as you used to do.

Typing *firemonkey window handle* into the internet search engine of my choice leads to many solutions, several of them right here on StackOverflow. Long story short: Use [FMX.Platform.Win.WindowHandleToPlatform(..)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Platform.Win.WindowHandleToPlatform) to convert.

Example:

```
implementation

uses
  Fmx.Platform.Win,
  WinApi.Windows;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    nativeWindowHandle: HWND;
begin
    nativeWindowHandle := Fmx.Platform.Win.WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle).Wnd;
    // TODO: Check for error when SetWindowPos returns false
    SetWindowPos(nativeWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOACTIVATE);
end;
```

Comment: That actually worked! I figured out that it's not the same type in VCL and FMX, but i didnt knew that i can change it that easily. Tnx a lot!